# Pass value of sessionStorage in javascript to <span> in html

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, cordova

I am developing an app with (JQM+cordova+backbone.js). I have 2 html pages. In the first page I have 1 textbox to input userID. so in the javascript file of the page i do

```
sessionStorage.userID=$("#userID").val();
```

in the second page i want to pass the value that i have stored in a  tag. how do i do it? i only know if i want to use textbox instead i can do it by using

```
<input value="<%= sessionStorage.userID %>">
```

any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: one field is `userID`, the other is `description`. Is this intended?

Comment: sorry, typo. i fixed it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery, it whould be something like this:

```
//write from session storage to span
window.sessionStorage.setItem("userID", $("#spanID").html());
//write from session storage to span
$("#spanID").html(window.sessionStorage.getItem("userID"));
```

In Underscore template:

```
<span id="spanID"><%= window.sessionStorage.getItem("userID") %></span>
```

Are you using a Backbone plugin to handle session storage?

Comment: thank you very much. this code solves my problem. just that i think you need to fix line 1 and 2. 
line 1 should be: //write from textbox to session storage
line 2 should be: window.sessionStorage.setItem("userID", $("#spanID).val());

Comment: jQuery .val() returns the value of an input or select, not the content of a span. To get the content of a span (or div) you use .html() (returns the innerHTML). This in case you want to read the content of the span. You mentionned you already knew how to read from the input.

Comment: actually, as in my question i am getting the content from a textbox input and i want to pass it to a span